# Content appears from a split second then disappears all together

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm downloading data from FireStore. Data is retrieved perfectly. I have the data and can print information. The issue is, when I tap on a text/label to push to the intended view, I perform the function using the `.onAppear` function. My variables, from my `ObservableClass` are `@Published`. I have the data and can even set elements based on the data retrieved. I'm using the MVVM approach and have done this a plethora of times throughout my project. However, this is the first time I have this particular issue. I've even used functions that are working in other views completely fine, yet in this particular view this problem persists. When I load/push this view, the data is shown for a split second and then the view/canvas is blank. Unless the elements are static i.e. `Text("Hello World")` the elements will disappear. I can't understand why the data just decides to disappear.

This is my code:

```
struct ProfileFollowingView: View {
    @ObservedObject var profileViewModel = ProfileViewModel()
    var user: UserModel
    
    func loadFollowing() {
        self.profileViewModel.loadCurrentUserFollowing(userID: self.user.uid)
    }
    var body: some View {
            ZStack {
               Color(SYSTEM_BACKGROUND_COLOUR)
                   .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                
                         VStack(alignment: .leading)  {
                             if !self.profileViewModel.isLoadingFollowing {
        
                                         ForEach(self.profileViewModel.following, id: \.uid) { user in
                                             VStack {
                                                Text(user.username).foregroundColor(.red)
                                                
                                             }
                                         }
                                         
                                         
                             }
                       
                             
                     
                         }
            } .onAppear(perform: {
                self.profileViewModel.loadCurrentUserFollowing(userID: self.user.uid)
            })
    }
}
```

This is my `loadFollowers` function:

```
func loadCurrentUserFollowing(userID: String) {
    isLoadingFollowing = true
    API.User.loadUserFollowing(userID: userID) { (user) in
        self.following = user
        self.isLoadingFollowing = false
    }
}
```

I've looked at my code that retrieves the data, and it's exactly like other features/functions I already have. It's just happens on this view.

Comment: Can you remove `VStack(alignment: .leading)` code and please try it. I haven't tried yet but I got many such unusual behaviour when I used `Vstack` multiple times. So please try.

Comment: @Sona I've tired. Still the same issue. I've even used DispatchMain.Qeue on my function.

Comment: When I tried with static values, your code works perfectly. Please debug your API call function to check whether `self.following` is nil or not. I haven't got any issues in your code :(

Comment: @Sona I had the same issue. Static variables are completely fine. I used/called other functioning that are working perfectly fine in my app and the same problem persists. I've using a NavigationLink that's pushing the view. And onAppear I'm calling the function.

Answer (score 2):

Change `@ObservedObject` to `@StateObject`

Update:
ObservedObject easily gets destroyed/recreated whenever a view is re-created, while StateObject stays/exists even when a view is re-created.
For more info watch this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VLUhZbz4arg

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `API.User.loadUserFollowing(userID:)` may be asynchronous - may run in the background. You need to update all `@Published` variables on the main thread:

```
func loadCurrentUserFollowing(userID: String) {
    isLoadingFollowing = true
    API.User.loadUserFollowing(userID: userID) { (user) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.following = user
            self.isLoadingFollowing = false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just tried and no luck. I've did try that perform, but on the .Appear() method in my view.

Comment: @SwiftUser Your code in onAppear runs on the main thread anyway. Just look for asynchronous functions that set `@Published`/`@State` properties.

Comment: Any idea why I need asynchronous functions now? Haven't needed them all this time. It's just seems weird.

Comment: @SwiftUser I'm just saying `API.User.loadUserFollowing(userID:)` looks like an asynchronous function - most API functions do.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried. No luck. Think it is a major bug in SwiftUI

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add like this: "DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter"

```
.onAppear {
       DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) {
             self.profileViewModel.loadCurrentUserFollowing(userID: self.user.uid) 
       }
 }
```